# How could I know the numbers of different atoms in Materials Studio?

Tags: materials-design, materials-engineering, materials-studio

I am building a model in the Materials Studio which includes many atoms, so I'd like to count the number of different atoms, is there any way to do that?

Comment: +1. But by "Material Studio" do you mean Material***s*** Studio which is distributed by BIOVIA (this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materials_Studio)?

Comment: @NikeDattani, Yes I am.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set your interface to show the *Properties Explorer*, then select all the atoms of your system and look at the *Properties Explorer*.

In the examples below, there are a periodic system and a molecular one.

For the periodic system you will find the information in the *Symmetry System* filter under the *Property Explorer*.

In case of the molecular system, the information is under the *Physical System* filter.

Setting up *Property Explorer*:
[image]

For a periodic system, the info is under *Symmetry System* filter:
[image]

For a molecular system, the info is under *Physical System* filter:
[image]

Comment: Well done Camps!